# Django template tag to output images from model

Tags: django, image, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I am new to Django and just started working on my first project. i have a mode located at common.utils.abstact_models.py:

```
class PhotoModel(BaseModel):
  submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
  caption = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  photo = FileBrowseField('Image (Initial Directory)', max_length=100, directory='uploads/')
  is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta
  abstract = True
```

maybe this also will be useful. i have another model:

```
class Photo(BaseModel):
  event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
  photo = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to="uploads/event_photos")
  is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i have pictures uploaded to **MEDIA_URL/uploads/event_photos**

i need to write a template tag to output photos of current user. Lets say 10 photos.
i almost dont have any code, i started from some.

```
from django import template
from common.utils.abstract_models.py import PhotoModel

register = template.Library()

def do_random_photos(parser, token):
  myobjects = PhotoModel.objects.all()
  return {'objects': myobjects}

class RandomPhotosNode(template.Node):
  def __init__(self, context):
  self.

def render(self, context):
  return
```

do you have any suggestions in writing this template tag?

Answer (score 1):

**output photos of current user**.your need add a filter ,use 'request.user.id' get current user's id. **show 10 photos** need Django's Pagination.

```
def show_photos(request):
  photos = PhotoModel.objects.filter(submitted_by=request.user.id)
  paginator = Paginator(photos,9)
  try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page',1))
  except ValueError:
    page = 1
  try:
    photos = paginator.page(page)
  except:
    photos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
  ctx = {'photos':photos}
  return render_to_response('a templates', ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

then, in you templates

```
{% for photo in photos.object_list %}
<img src="{{ photo.photo }}" />
{% endfor %}
```